# 'This site can’t be reached' after closing ec2 console tab on browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance, web-hosting

i am created a travel agency management website with Django and i hosted it in AWS free tier ec2 instance then with instance IP address and port number 8000 i activate my server by

`python3 manage.py run server`

now website working smoothly with all functionality

the problem is begin with when i close ec2 instance command-line tool or logout aws website the server also terminate and the browser show this message when i access my website
`Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 16.170.229.47:8000.

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.`
```

how can i keep my website on live even i close my ec2 or aws tab on browser